# what is the method used to fetch the cached string response using android -volley?

Tags: android, caching, android-volley

1)I am caching the string network response from the server using the method

```
request.setShouldCache(true);
```

2)I am trying to access the cached data using

```
System.out.println("the cached data"+new String(request.getCacheEntry().data));
```

This throws a null pointer exception  . 
3)I printed a output statment in HTTPHeaderparser.java .The data is printed properly .

```
System.out.println("the data value is"+new String(entry.data) );
```

4)So i guess I made some mistake while fetching the cached data .

Can some one help me out ?

Answer (score 1):

The cache entry in the request it's not filled until you run the request, so you should directly call the cache to test if it contains a value with

```
mQueue.getCache().get(request.getCacheKey())
```

as bogdan put in the comment if what you want to do is get a value from cache without making a network request.

this method is fast and you can call from the UI Thread. It will return the cache entry if available even if it's expired, but you can call the isExpired() method to know if the response it's outdated.

It returns the data even if stale, because you can choose to show it while you refresh the data in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the method `parseCacheHeaders(NetworkResponse)` from the class `HttpHeaderParser`. There are some conditions there for caching the response, so the library will only cache the response if the server will provide some headers. If you want to override this, you will have to override the method `parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse)` from the `Request` class and call a different method for parsing the cache headers from the server.
**Update**
It seems I misunderstood the question a bit, for accessing Volley cache, assuming your RequestQueue instance is mQueue, you can do mQueue.getCache().get(request.getCacheKey()).

Comment: I don't want to override the information sent by server ...To be more clear volley fetches the response either from the cache or from the server ....I want to know how volley fetches the data from the cache ??And I was able to cache the data..I switched off my wifi and executed my app ...App was able to fetch the data from the cache ...

Comment: ohh, then all you need to do is, assuming your `RequestQueue` instance is `mQueue`, `mQueue.getCache().get(request.getCacheKey())`

Comment: I have a small issue now ..Does the volley stores the data in the cache even when max age=0 ?Because the response is returned  when I use this function(mQueue.getCache().get(request.getCacheKey()) [Note  max age=0 for this response] ??

Comment: It depends on the answer from the server, if you want to know exactly how the caching is done, look into the source code of Volley